# How do I hide a form element when all of a set of elements have a certain value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

On a form I have 3 questions with Yes/No radio options. If ANY of them are Yes, then a 4th question appears. I'm struggling to make the 4th question hide again if all 3 questions are reset to No. Probably a non-existent case, but I would prefer to be thorough.

I wrote a custom function triggered on click (when value != 'Yes') for each question to check the rest of the values and then update the 4th, but it seems like their values are not getting updated. q6, q7, and q8 in the function stay = 'Yes'. I thought my function would have access to the live form, but I must be doing something wrong?

```
        //question_6exp
    $("[name = question_6]").change(function()
    {
        if ( $(this).val() == 'Yes' )
        {
            $("#question_6exp").show();
            $("#question_9").show();
        }
        else
        {
            $("#question_6exp").hide();
            $("#question_9").hide_question9();
        }
    });

    //question_7exp
    $("[name = question_7]").change(function()
    {
        if ( $(this).val() == 'Yes' )
        {
            $("#question_7exp").show();
            $("#question_9").show();
        }
        else
        {
            $("#question_7exp").hide();
            $("#question_9").hide_question9();
        }
    });

    //question_8exp
    $("[name = question_8]").change(function()
    {
        if ( $(this).val() == 'Yes' )
        {
            $("#question_8exp").show();
            $("#question_9").show();
        }
        else
        {
            $("#question_8exp").hide();
            $("#question_9").hide_question9();
        }
    });

    //function hide_question9()
    $.fn.hide_question9 = function()
    {


        var q6 = $("[name = question_6]").val();
        var q7 = $("[name = question_7]").val();
        var q8 = $("[name = question_8]").val();
        //alert('TEST: '+q6+q7+q8);
        if ( (q6 == 'No') && (q7 == 'No') && (q8 == 'No') )
        {
            //$("#question_9").hide();
            return this.hide();
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
```

**UPDATE:** 
I updated my code based on the 2 responses I received below. Unfortunately, neither worked. I added a class to the 3 questions to make it easier to select just those 3. I tweaked JoDev's layout mostly. I commented out the code within the else state and tried Aguardientico code there - it is currently commented out.

```
$(".temp1").change(function()
    {
        var myName = $(this).attr('name');

        if ( $(this).val() == 'Yes' )
        {
            $("#question_9").show();
            $("#"+myName+"exp").show();
        }
        else
        {//alert($(this).val());
            $("#"+myName+"exp").hide();

            var alltoNo = true;
            $(".temp1").each(function()
            {
                if ( $(this).val() == 'Yes' )
                {
                    alltoNo = false;
                }

                //return;
            });

            if ( alltoNo )
                $("[name = question_9]").hide();

            /*if ( $("[name=question_6][value=Yes]:checked").length == 0 )
                $("[name = question_9]").hide();*/
        }
    });
```

Comment: do not put spaces between attribute and value `(name=question_6)` instead of `(name = question_6)`

Comment: Why not? I always do it this way for readability and it works just fine.

Comment: You can use the `rel` attrib to point what to show or hide... Or `data-something` attribs! (why not : `data-show='question_1;anotherselector_5' data-hide='question_exp8'`)... Do you understand what I mean?

Answer (score 0):

This is an simpliest way to do it (just a beginning)

```
$('[name^="question_"]:not([name="question_9"])').change(function() {
    if ( $(this).val() == 'Yes' )
    {
       $("#question_9").show();
       $("#question_"+$(this).attr('name').replace('question_', '')+"exp").show();
    } else {

       $("#question_"+$(this).attr('name').replace('question_', '')+"exp").hide();

       var alltoNO = true;
       $('[name^="question_"]:not([name="question_9"])').each(function() {
          if($(this).val() == 'Yes') {
             alltoNo = false;
          }
          return;
       });
       if(alltoNo) {
         $('[name="question_9"]').hide();
       }
    }
});
```

Comment: I think I see what you are doing there. Unfortunately I have other questions on the form with the same naming scheme, so I cannot get by with a single change function like that. 

But I could add a unique class selector to my 3 particular questions and then use the .each function to loop through them. I will try it out and update the post.

Answer (score 0):

Try with something like this:

HTML:

```
<input type="radio" name="question_6" value="Yes"/> 6 Yes
<input type="radio" name="question_6" value="No"/> 6 No
<input type="radio" name="question_7" value="Yes"/> 7 Yes
<input type="radio" name="question_7" value="No"/> 7 No
<input type="radio" name="question_8" value="Yes"/> 8 Yes
<input type="radio" name="question_8" value="No"/> 8 No

<div id="question_6exp">Q6</div>
<div id="question_7exp">Q7</div>
<div id="question_8exp">Q8</div>
<div id="question_9exp">Q9</div>
```

JS:

```
$('[name=question_6], [name=question_7], [name=question_8]').change(function(){
    if (this.value=="Yes") {
        $("#" + this.name + "exp").show();
        $("#question_9exp").show();
    } else {
        $("#" + this.name + "exp").hide();
        if ($("[name=question_6][value=Yes]:checked, [name=question_7][value=Yes]:checked, [name=question_8][value=Yes]:checked").length == 0) {
            $("#question_9exp").hide();
        }
    }
});
```